# Use variable of current Eloquent in `WITH` method - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have this code (which won't work):

```
$accessuser = AccessUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
              ->with(['overtimes' => function ($qry) use ($accessuser) {
                  $qry->where('waiting_for', $accessuser->access_level)->get();
              }])->get();
```

Obviously, I just want to get the value of `access_level` column and compare it to `waiting_for` column.

Is there any solution for this? Let me know if you need any additional information about my table structure, etc.

**EDITED**

Here's my `AccesschartUserMap` model:

```
Schema::create('accesschart_user_maps', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('accesschart_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('access_level')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('accesschart_id')
        ->references('id')->on('access_charts')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

My `Overtime` model:

```
Schema::create('overtimes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('accesschart_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('remarks_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('waiting_for')->nullable();
    $table->datetime('date_from');
    $table->datetime('date_to');
    $table->longtext('reason');
    $table->longtext('remarks')->nullable();
    $table->integer('status')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('remarks_by')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Here's the Query that I want to achieve:

```
SELECT accessuser.user_id,accessuser.accesschart_id,accessuser.access_level,overtimes.waiting_for
FROM accesschart_user_maps as accessuser
INNER JOIN overtimes ON accessuser.accesschart_id = overtimes.id
WHERE accessuser.user_id = 7 and accessuser.access_level=overtimes.waiting_for
```

Comment: please five more informations, about  AccessUser, Overtime and an example of what you need

Comment: Hi! @yoeunes, I updated my question. Please see the edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the "query builder" version of the query that you want to achieve.

```
$accessuser = DB::table('accesschart_user_maps as accessuser')
->join('overtimes', 'accessuser.accesschart_id', '=', 'overtimes.id')
->select('accessuser.user_id','accessuser.accesschart_id','accessuser.access_level','overtimes.waiting_for')
->where('accessuser.user_id', \Auth::User()->id)
->where('accessuser.access_level', 'overtimes.waiting_for')
->get();
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
$accessuser = DB::table('accesschart_user_maps as accessuser')
->select('accessuser.user_id as user_id','accessuser.accesschart_id as accesschart_id','accessuser.access_level as access_level','overtimes.waiting_for as waiting_for')
->join('overtimes','overtimes.id','=','accessuser.accesschart_id')
->where('accessuser.user_id','=',7)
->where('accessuser.access_level','=','overtimes.waiting_for')
->get();
```